# Quantum Physics - What is the probability of it being in specific state (Stuck on question)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, hilbert-space, born-rule

The normalised wavefunction for an electron in an infinite 1D potential well of length 65 pm can be written:
$$\psi=(0.038 \psi_{n=1})+(-0.227\ i \psi_{n=10})+(g \psi_{n=5}).$$ If the state is measured, there are three possible results (i.e. it is in the $n=1$, $10$ or $5$ state). What is the probability (in %) that it is in the $n=5$ state?

---

I am doing some revision and got stuck on this question, just can't seem to find what I mean in the Feynman lectures and my uni notes are terrible, any help?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a normalised linear combination of (orthogonal) states like this, the probability of measuring one of them is the *absolute square* of the coefficient in the combination: If

$$\Psi = a_1\psi_1+a_2\psi_2+...$$
where $|a_1|^2+|a_2|^2+... = 1$

then

$$P(\psi_1) = \left|a_1\right|^2, P(\psi_2) = \left|a_2\right|^2$$etc.

Slightly more generally, if you know you have a state $|\psi>$ then the probability of measuring a (possibly different) state $|\phi>$ is $\left|<\phi|\psi>\right|^2$.